# PushViewController not animating

Tags: ios, swift

I am using this code to push a viewController:

```
let internetUsageHistoryVc = UIStoryboard(name: "Usage", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InternetUsageHistoryController") as! InternetUsageHistoryController

internetUsageHistoryVc.internetUsageCardViewModel = cardVm

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(internetUsageHistoryVc, animated: true)
```

The navigation is working but the animation does not seem to be working. 
It might be related with a bunch of broken constraints I have in to screen I am navigating to... but not sure...

Has anybody faced this issue?... any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Have u turned **Reduce Motion** in **Accessibility** ON? If YES, turn it OFF. Try restarting your device and see if animation is working.

Comment: It is off.... It might be related with a bunch of broken constraints I have in to screen I am navigating to....

Comment: Yea maybe. I too have faced this for unknown reasons, but goes off on its own.

Comment: Where are you running that code

Comment: in a view controller...